# New Permission Requirements for DeveloperName Field

Tags: release-update

I am getting an error in one of my sandboxes under profile settings, "The user license doesn't allow the permission: ViewDeveloperName"   The only thing I found on this is this article:  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000362829&type=1

But I don't understand how I provide access to the DeveloperName field?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Frd

Comment: the article says to give the user access to DeveloperName in a permission set or profile

Comment: Yes it does.  But I can't find anywhere in the profile to provide that access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission is called `View DeveloperName` and exists in System Permissions[image]

If you are not seeing it in a sandbox, try going to [Company Settings | Match Production Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335272&type=1) and if still not visible, file a Support Case

Comment: Thank you!  My issue is the target sandbox has not been upgraded to the new release.  The source sandbox has.  Thanks again!!!!